# Custom formatter for std::format for std::wstring GCC

Tags: c++, c++20, libstdc++, wstring, stdformat

I'm trying to make a formatter for `std::format` that would take a `std::wstring` and format it to a `std::string`. The idea being that I'd replace all the non-convertible chars with '`?`'.

```
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<>
struct std::formatter<std::wstring> : public std::formatter<std::string> {

    template<typename ParsContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParsContext& ctx) {
        return std::begin(ctx);
    }

    template<typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const std::wstring &obj, FormatContext &ctx) const {
        std::string result{};
        for(const auto & wch : obj){
            if(wch < 0x80){
                std::format_to(std::back_inserter(result), "{}", static_cast<char>(wch));
            }else{
                std::format_to(std::back_inserter(result), "?");
            }
        }
        return std::formatter<std::string>::format(result, ctx);
    }
};

int main(){
    std::wstring test{L"Hello wide world.こんにちは、안녕하세요!\n"};
    std::cout << std::format("{}", test); 
}
```

Results in the following compiler error: (small sample, full error at compiler explorer)

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/format:3029:19: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
 3029 |             _M_set(_Td{__v.data(), __v.size()});
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:146:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_string_view(const _CharT*, size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; size_type = long unsigned int]'
  146 |       basic_string_view(const _CharT* __str, size_type __len) noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:146:39: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'wchar_t*' to 'const char*'
  146 |       basic_string_view(const _CharT* __str, size_type __len) noexcept
```

Using libc++ with clang it works [Working with Clang with libc++](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwAnKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIAAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YkpdpgO2UIETMQEuT5%2BQbaY9iUMjc0EZdFxCcm2TS1t%2BZ0KE4MRw5WjSQCUtqhexMjsHADU%2B7vm/hHI3liH/m78xCxMBCb%2B2CYaAIIHh2bHDKde5w9us2IEWADyer3eRxOZ0wFzcTkBmFYoOeLxR7wImBYqQMGP%2ByPBB0BXgcu1m6BAIGutwIGOI/zJFIA7oDgaDdiBdqkvLFaHhkKSCOTKSRqbT6YKKSyjGyTAB2KyvNHvA4YrE4zD/AgAT1SjFYMOUzQUHkEmFU90eSuVuzQDFmZtSxF2TC8RE5RswEENxGNsjN9zMADYbQRVCtDvKrdaDsRMARNgwBUL4sAIhAHGGHgq3tG5QARFFR9GY7F3DWXbW65hsXYAMRFdxNGPN%2BJz1pdbqpd3TAlmSaZUuAH0DqFi2lIdYbrT95uHGfDtr7cuz0eVDJAg92sYUXlo90jsoL/hXq4O1x7doIztdqGHu0ZyAQ7N2o%2B0K2XRdP%2BzwVAgD6f/y7BoqhJBo76RgSX6ruuXYEAA%2BkQEDrrETDIAA1nBERKC0CQQNuu4EGsHxmB%2Bh7mGYE6zHcfJwaIsz/I%2BzSgn%2Bj4rO%2Bx6fl%2B%2BbdEoH6QVB1owVOCGoEhEogCh6GYXaCS0nhmA7nuRHkQ8tbkexJ4Cfs%2BaccqOn8ausbxsQiZCTcdxipc66DqCFKwfJikEBO85Zrp%2BlthGR7ZlGERXrcabgZpa7icyBBAkYuwYvR8qhORAAS3S0LejJ4OcjIkLQ6AAHQmNg/gmEkXAmIE%2BV5QVJElbl%2BWFSYLxWGVNUvEVDVFS8akNRoBXNW4xUAKwFUkuVWEk/WBP12AFmNxWDdgPVJJIJgWDNPWBKigSSGAYAmL1bgMCpZEcQZhLiWgrqwoBZnUhA%2B1WGRZgUZFCmEVmhz8fmHBrLQnC9bwfgcFopCoJwPWWNYpIbFsMJHDwpAEJoH1rGhICSIGWW9YVkj%2BJIXD%2BBoGiyvdgb6Jwki/fDgOcLwCggBosPw2scCwDAiAoKgWJ0Ak5CUGg7P0IkpyGMAXCyhoTAKNhTk0HuCTUxAsTk7EETNFqnAw4rzDEFqADyY51HD3C8DzbCCFrDC0Cr/28FgsReMAbhiLQ1MG6QWC3EY4iWy7eCxvUABuCnk2adSujsAO%2Bd05O8rExDKx4WDk2FeAsKrH18AYwAKAAangmCMlrVYpzIggiGI7BSEX8hKGo5O6Fw%2BiCyg1jWPoeCxNTsDVuwVAsE5/uJGFXgMGhbGA6kvROwAtGSDx5qYoOWGYGi7FPgpRzPUdz1Yli8KgfdAlg7cQGstT1M4ECuFMfh12ECwVFUehFFkAiXw/GRPwwQx36Mdcn70/STJ4doehf4NDmJ/EYiQf5zBflAgY4CliQOPhDbYEhPrfTJp7IGewQKBgnoGSQNoDARWFllDQWUuC7AgGLCW2QFDhggLgQgJAPj%2BC4CsXg%2BstAjwQIiLAiQj6kCRr1XqWUkisK4L1WUvUzBJBkb1FGRMvocFJqQZOkhZRZVlFwQIgYkgjUkDIswvV/BEz%2BgDLBVMaZ00tgzZmEAkAbAIFyJyFBz74CIPvPQ/Bi6iHEOXbxlcVDqE9rXUgjIY6pBTmgjgP1SBmJ3pwLWrpnEvioLsHBeCCEC2IRoshFCqHi1krQ%2BhHheYJBYWwjh9M1g8KYHwyg0SVHJ2kVlGRGhxGSEkcLFGvU4nkwsbYKxnCEaCJAMYrK2MRqBnRoGQIgQzCyllNIJR/gMHmMptYrh0SzBrISRwKpNi1h90yM4SQQA)

Any help would be appreciated.

[Failing with GCC/Clang libstd++](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwAnKSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIAAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BwemZjgLhkTEs8YkpdpgO2UIETMQEuT5%2BQbaY9iUMjc0EZdFxCcm2TS1t%2BZ0KE4MRw5WjSQCUtqhexMjsHADU%2B7vm/hHI3liH/m78xCxMBCb%2B2CYaAIIHh2bHDKde5w9us2IEWADyer3eRxOZ0wFzcTkBmFYoOeLxR7wImBYqQMGP%2ByPBB0BXgcu1m6BAIGutwIGOI/zJFIA7oDgaDdiBdqkvLFaHhkKSCOTKSRqbT6YKKSyjGyTAB2KyvNHvA4YrE4zD/AgAT1SjFYMOUzQUHkEmFU90eSuVuzQDFmZtSxF2TC8RE5RswEENxGNsjN9zMADYbQRVCtDvKrdaDsRMARNgwBUL4sAIhAHGGHgq3tG5QARFFR9GY7F3DWXbW65hsXYAMRFdxNGPN%2BJz1pdbqpd3TAlmSaZUuAH0DqFi2lIdYbrT95uHGfDtr7cuz0eVDJAg92sYUXlo90jsoL/hXq4O1x7doIztdqGHu0ZyAQ7N2o%2B0K2XRdP%2BzwVAgD6f/y7BoqhJBo76RgSX6ruuXYEAA%2BkQEDrrETDIAA1nBERKC0CQQNuu4EGsHxmB%2Bh7mGYE6zHcfJwaIsz/I%2BzSgn%2Bj4rO%2Bx6fl%2B%2BbdEoH6QVB1owVOCGoEhEogCh6GYXaCS0nhmA7nuRHkQ8tbkexJ4Cfs%2BaccqOn8ausbxsQiZCTcdxipc66DqCFKwfJikEBO85Zrp%2BlthGR7ZlGERXrcabgZpa7icyBBAkYuwYvR8qhORAAS3S0LejJ4OcjIkLQ6AAHQmNg/gmEkXAmIE%2BV5QVJElbl%2BWFSYLxWGVNUvEVDVFS8akNRoBXNW4xUAKwFUkuVWEk/WBP12AFmNxWDdgPVJJIJgWDNPWBKigSSGAYAmL1bgMCpZEcQZhLiWgrqwoBZnUhA%2B1WGRZgUZFCmEVmhz8fmHBrLQnC9bwfgcFopCoJwPWWNYpIbFsMJHDwpAEJoH1rGhICSIGWW9YVkj%2BJIXD%2BBoGiyvdgb6Jwki/fDgOcLwCggBosPw2scCwDAiAoKgWJ0Ak5CUGg7P0IkwA4xRNB7gk1MQLE5OxBEzRapwMNS8wxBagA8mOdRw9wvA82wgjKwwtCy/9vBYLEXjAG4Yi0NTmukFgtxGOIRu23gsb1AAbgp5NmnUro7ADvndOTvKxMQMseFg5NhXgLByx9fAGMACgAGp4JgjLK1WscyIIIhiOwUjZ/IShqOTuhcPohjGNY1j6HgsTU7A1bsFQLBOR7iRhV4DBoWxgOpL01sALRkg8eamKDlhmADqDt0CWANxAay1PUzgQK4Ux%2BOXYQLBUVR6EUWQCBv%2B8ZIfDBDLvozl8vvT9JMnjtHoN8NHMF8jIk19zMfn8DG/Swf0vCG2wJCfW%2BmTJ2QM9ggUDIPQMkhdjAGQPyHGWUzC7AgLgQgJAPj%2BC4CsXgGstC9wQIiLAiRF6kCRr1XqWUki4K4L1WUvUzBJBYb1FGRMvocFJqQGOkhZRZVlFwQIgYkgjUkCwswvV/BEz%2BtPSmtgaZ0yNgzZmEAkAbAIFyJyFA174CIHPPQ/Ac6iHEAXYxRcVDqCdmXUgjJQ6pFjqAjgP1SByN4JA5WrptEvioLsaBsD4GIOQf4VB6CPC8wSDgvBBD6ZrBIUwMhlBnE8Jjsw1BoF6GSEYVwWUKNepuPJpAqmSjCEI0oSAaRWVsYjUDOjQMgRAhmFlHk4mHB/DgPkRwWJKjnFmE6R4hRZTe7t0yM4SQQA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: You should not specialize for type you don't own.

Comment: This should be a bug in libstdc++ IMO, noted that `std::wcout << std::format(L"{}", test);`  [works](https://godbolt.org/z/76ovazs46).

Comment: Use a wrapper [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nWsxWedYz).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in libstdc++ ([PR 112607](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112607)) and has been [fixed in the GCC-trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/4K5Wbh3T9).

Note that as the comments say, specializing `std::wstring` for `std::formatter` is not allowed because it does not depend on program-defined types, although `std::wstring` with custom traits or allocator classes may be valid options.